# How to connect TV through Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I used this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // Whenever a remote Bluetooth device is found
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                adapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    };

    private ToggleButton toggleButton;
    private ListView listview;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private static final int ENABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int DISCOVERABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    private static final int DISCOVERABLE_DURATION = 300;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothServerSocket bluetoothServerSocket;
    private final static UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("fc5ffc49-00e3-4c8b-9cf1-6b72aad1001a");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String  itemValue = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String MAC = itemValue.substring(itemValue.length() - 17);
                BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
                // Initiate a connection request in a separate thread
                ConnectingThread t = new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice);
                t.start();

            }
        });
    }

    public void onToggleClicked(View view) {

        adapter.clear();

        ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) view;

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oop! Your device does not support Bluetooth",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            toggleButton.setChecked(false);
        } else {

            if (toggleButton.isChecked()){ // to turn on bluetooth
                if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    // A dialog will appear requesting user permission to enable Bluetooth
                    Intent enableBluetoothIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBluetoothIntent, ENABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device has already been enabled." +
                                    "\n" + "Scanning for remote Bluetooth devices...",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // To discover remote Bluetooth devices
                    discoverDevices();
                    // Make local device discoverable by other devices
                    makeDiscoverable();
                }
            } else { // Turn off bluetooth

                bluetoothAdapter.disable();
                adapter.clear();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device is now disabled.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == ENABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE) {

            // Bluetooth successfully enabled!
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ha! Bluetooth is now enabled." +
                                "\n" + "Scanning for remote Bluetooth devices...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Make local device discoverable by other devices
                makeDiscoverable();

                // To discover remote Bluetooth devices
                discoverDevices();

            } else { // RESULT_CANCELED as user refused or failed to enable Bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not enabled.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Turn off togglebutton
                toggleButton.setChecked(false);
            }
        } else if (requestCode == DISCOVERABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE){

            if (resultCode == DISCOVERABLE_DURATION){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device is now discoverable by other devices for " +
                                DISCOVERABLE_DURATION + " seconds",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to enable discoverability on your device.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void discoverDevices(){
        // To scan for remote Bluetooth devices
        if (bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discovering other bluetooth devices...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discovery failed to start.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void makeDiscoverable(){
        // Make local device discoverable
        Intent discoverableIntent = new
                Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, DISCOVERABLE_DURATION);
        startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, DISCOVERABLE_BT_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Register the BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
        ListeningThread listening = new  ListeningThread();
        listening.start();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
    private class ListeningThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothServerSocket bluetoothServerSocket;

        public ListeningThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket temp = null;
            try {
                temp = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(getString(R.string.app_name), uuid);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bluetoothServerSocket = temp;
        }

        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
            // This will block while listening until a BluetoothSocket is returned
            // or an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bluetoothSocket = bluetoothServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
                // If a connection is accepted
                if (bluetoothSocket != null) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A connection has been accepted.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    // Manage the connection in a separate thread

                    try {
                        bluetoothServerSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Cancel the listening socket and terminate the thread
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                bluetoothServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private class ConnectingThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;

        public ConnectingThread(BluetoothDevice device) {

            BluetoothSocket temp = null;
            bluetoothDevice = device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                temp = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bluetoothSocket = temp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel any discovery as it will slow down the connection
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                // This will block until it succeeds in connecting to the device
                // through the bluetoothSocket or throws an exception
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
                Log.e("TAG" , "Bluetooth socket is connected.");
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                connectException.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    bluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                    closeException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // Code to manage the connection in a separate thread
        /*
            manageBluetoothConnection(bluetoothSocket);
        */
        }

        // Cancel an open connection and terminate the thread
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

I got log.

```
D/BluetoothAdapter: cancelDiscovery
09-13 12:57:28.321 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection D/BluetoothAdapter: cancelDiscovery = true
09-13 12:57:28.326 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
09-13 12:57:28.326 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection D/BluetoothSocket: connect(): myUserId = 0
09-13 12:57:28.326 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
09-13 12:57:28.336 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection D/BluetoothSocket: connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[43]}
09-13 12:57:29.976 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
09-13 12:57:29.976 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:739)
09-13 12:57:29.976 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:750)
09-13 12:57:29.976 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:478)
09-13 12:57:29.976 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection W/System.err:     at sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection.MainActivity$ConnectingThread.run(MainActivity.java:273)
09-13 12:57:29.976 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection D/BluetoothSocket: close() in, this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@3c92d388, channel: -1, state: INIT
09-13 12:57:29.976 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection D/BluetoothSocket: close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@3c92d388, channel: -1, mSocketIS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@2a27b121, mSocketOS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream@2b64a946mSocket: android.net.LocalSocket@17939707 impl:android.net.LocalSocketImpl@1845a034 fd:FileDescriptor[43]
09-13 12:57:29.976 5687-5884/sony.ir.dumadu.com.bluetoothconnection D/BluetoothSocket: Closing mSocket: android.net.LocalSocket@17939707 impl:android.net.LocalSocketImpl@1845a034 fd:FileDescriptor[43]
```

So I need to remove log:

> java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1.

Please help me.

Comment: What's profile you want to connect with the TV? if it is HID then you should initialize the connection from TV first time; I see your code you created a RFCOMM channel waiting for connection; strange.

Comment: Android phone need to have connect .@GuoXingmin

Comment: Then how can you confirm that TV have the sane profile you wanted?